# Data binding and promise in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise, angular-http

I have the following factory I use to return a http promise with the user data from the server

```
(function () {

  angular.module('BlurAdmin.theme')
      .factory('getData', function($http){

    var service = {};
    service.objData = null;

    service.savePromise = function(objData) {

      service.objData = objData;
    }

    service.getSavedPromise = function() {

      return service.objData;
    }


    service.getDataFromServer = function() {

      var promise = $http.get('/admin/data');

      service.savePromise(promise);
    }

    return service;

  });

})();
```

I launch this http request at the run method of the app.

In another controller I have done the following

```
getData.getSavedPromise().then(function (data) {
  $scope.newVisits = data.data.data.newVisitors;
});

var pieColor = baUtil.hexToRGB(baConfig.colors.defaultText, 0.2);
$scope.charts = [{
  color: pieColor,
  description: 'New Visits',
  stats: '$ ' + $scope.newVisits,
  icon: 'person',
}, {
  color: pieColor,
  description: 'Purchases',
  stats: '$ 89,745',
  icon: 'money',
}, {
  color: pieColor,
  description: 'Active Users',
  stats: '178,391',
  icon: 'face',
}, {
  color: pieColor,
  description: 'Returned',
  stats: '32,592',
  icon: 'refresh',
}
];
```

The Data structure is a little messed up and I need to fix it but that is beside the point.

I use for example

```
<div class="description-stats">{{ ::chart.stats }}</div>
```

In the html.

The issue is that the data is not being bind and I see undefined in the page.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: do you have `{{charts }}` as undefined ?

Comment: {{ ::chart.stats }} the first element which is '$ ' + $scope.newVisits in the controller

Comment: really can't understand your problem, detail your question more or provides some fiddler /plunker.

Comment: In short, I'm trying to bind data which is coming from the server using promise to what I'm displaying to the user. at the beginning of the app I launch the http request and save the promise. In another controller I get the promise and using the then function saving the data to $scope.newVisits which is also what I'm showing the user but I get undefined instead.